# ImageView selector with images of different size

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm trying to solve the following problem: I have to images, one for normal state and another is for the 'active' mode which is similar to normal except it has glow above the edges. The active state image is larger than normal image, so that the active area stays the same.

So the problem is how to make ImageView adjust its size with selector? Currently it picks the size of the larger image and stretches the other image to the full size.

Thanks,
Anton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not add a transparent margin around the smaller image so that it is in fact the same size as the other one?